# How to use grep command to extract number in a text file

Tags: shell, grep

I have a cookie file,I just want to extract the number before the .jpg extension using grep command ..how can i do it

USERSTAFFPHOTO  09480106177557.jpg

I want to copy 09480106177557

Comment: grep -no 'name="[0-9]*"' filename

Comment: You can remove the -n option if you like as this is the line number

Answer (score 0):

`echo "USERSTAFFPHOTO 09480106177557.jpg" | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,}'`

Comment: `{1,}` is a really clumsy way to write `+`.

Comment: @tripleee: thanks, point noted ! also, would be great if you can help me to understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

You should chain 2 grep commands, the first one to get the file name along with the `.jpg` extension and the second one to get only the number from the file name:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+\.jpg' | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```

Otherwise, you would get all the numbers that exist in the file with or without the `.jpg` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Why restrict yourself to a particular tool?  Do you want the number, or do you want to use grep?  If the format is fixed, I would do this with `tr`:

```
echo USERSTAFFPHOTO 09480106177557.jpg | tr -cd [0-9]
```

If this is one line in a file and you need to filter it out, try awk:

```
awk '/USERSTAFFPHOTO/{print $2}' FS=' |\\.' input
```